# How to recognize pattern in a sequence (array)

Tags: pattern-recognition, pattern-matching

How do I recognize a know pattern in a sequence of numbers?

I have two known pattern like this: `1, 2, 3` and `1, 3, 2`

I have a data set looking like this: `1, 1, 3, 1, 1, 2, 2, 1, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3`

I need a function (mathmatical operation) that tells me, that this pattern is closer to `1, 2, 3` than to `1, 3, 2` as I want to have the focus on the sequence. The number of appearance doesn't matter and also noise is fine. I thought of convolution but I am not sure how to apply it and what to look for.

Comment: Why is it closer to $(1, 2, 3)$? If you can define your criteria of closeness precisely enough, you can write an algorithm (e.g. such algorithms exist fo string matching and DNA sequences and what not - but the criteria they use tend to be specific to the application area).

Comment: As said by @NickD : you have to give a precise definition of the degree of proximity of 2 sequences : is it the number of transpositions (exchange of 2 elements) you need to apply to the first one to obtain the second one ; do these transpositions have to be done with neighbours, etc.